# Link part of SVG img that is included with picture source tag

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have different SVG images that are included in `<picture>` tag based on viewport.

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="/banner-375.svg" media="(max-width: 375px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-480.svg" media="(max-width: 480px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-767.svg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-991.svg" media="(max-width: 991px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-1366.svg" media="(max-width: 1366px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-1600.svg" media="(max-width: 1600px)">
   <source srcset="/banner-1920.svg">
   <img src="/banner-991.svg"/>
</picture>
```

Inside that svgs I have call to action button that needs to be clickable.

- I found a way to solve that by using inline SVG and surround button
  with `a` tag. This doesn't suit  my needs because I have 7 different
  images that would need to be inline.
- Use `<map>`. Button in SVG images are positioned on different places so that would be a bunch of code.

Is there a more cleaner way to link just button element inisde those SVG images.

The following image is SVG along with the button.

[image]

Comment: Use one svg image that's inline and have it adjust itself via internal media queries and also have it contain the link.

Comment: I need to use picture tag because of image dimensions that needs to be loaded on different screens. I dont want 1920px on mobile device. So I don't understand how can I use just one inline SVG. Do you have any references with an example?

Comment: As I said you can use media queries to adapt the SVG image to the screen. You're already doing that to select differerent SVG images so just use the same mechanism within a single SVG image to adapt it to screen sizes.

Comment: What do you mean under adapt the SVG image to the screen. It's not about a position on the screen. Images are different based on the media query and it's never the same. Button is never on the same position. Please put some link to see how I can solve this

Comment: You'd need to explain how the images are different, ideally with some code. You also need to explain what your problem is with using media queries to do different things since you're using them already.

Comment: I have placed a code and explained a problem, and never mentioned media query was a problem. I want to make button inside SVG image clickable. Have you ever used picture tag? That is for loading different image on different screen size. That's why they are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229381/discussion-between-andrea-and-robert-longson).